# HighCharts Small issue

Tags: highcharts

Firtst of all I want to provide my licence number : 100027921001500

We are experiencing some small issues that really can affect the UX and the single help that we're asking is :

1. An advice for solving this situation, when we have tick lines with 1 , sometimes, randomly, and when zooming, the tickline from the top is 1px detached from the first one : A sample : http://snag.gy/DoXVX.jpg
2. What options can be found to manipulate the label texts , as you can see on top, we don't have the total power to manipulate the  element of the SVG in Css , and we don't have different browsers support, what advice you have regarding this ? ( Same screenshot )

Thank you,

Mihai

Comment: For #1, you'll need to provide the chart code and/or a fiddle example of the chart for which you have this problem. Do you have multiple axes? Or is that a single axis line that is being distorted?  For #2 you'll have to be a lot more specific - and it should really be a separate post.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rxd04mk5/1/ Here's a example, if you zoom in and out you'll see the error regenerating. as described in the screneshot above.

Comment: Could you fix your demo wihch contains many syntax errors?

Comment: Yes, here's an example , sorry about the first link , my bad : http://jsfiddle.net/03jtab0o/20/